# JavaFX: TextArea automatic height expanding without scrollbar

Tags: javafx-8, uitextarea

Can I force the **TextArea** control to **automatic expanding the height**?

In the following case, I would like to see the scrollbar at **ScrollPane** control, not at **TextArea** control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <VBox style="-fx-background-color: bisque">
        <TextField/>
        <TextArea VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="20.0"/>
            </VBox.margin>
        </TextArea>
    </VBox>
</ScrollPane>
```

[image: TextArea expanding the height]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, your `TextArea` is in a `ScrollPane`? If this is the case, I do not see any interest, `TextArea` already has its own `ScrollBar`. you still want to hide the `ScrollBar` of it and display that of the `ScrollPane` when the `TextArea` expands?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The user then scrolling with the whole content (`ScrollPane`) and not only with the `TextArea` content.

Comment: @BoHalim I added illustrating image.

Comment: With this schema the `TextField` will be hidden after the extension !

Comment: @BoHalim Yes, I want such behavior. Scrolling with the whole content of the `ScrollPane`.

Answer (score 1):

For now the only solution that is close to your problem is given by **@Uluk Biy**, that i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588765/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-stretch-to-fill-the-content-expanding-the-parent-in-t), what i did is just fit his logic, and hide the `ScrollBars`. **The only problem** is the size of the `TextArea` which is binded to that of the `Text` and so it starts with a `minimum height` at the beginning of the edition, here is the complete code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launcher extends Application{

private Pane root = new Pane();
private Scene scene;

private ScrollPane scroller;
private Pane content = new Pane();

private TextField textF = new TextField();
private TextArea textA = new TextArea();

private Text textHolder = new Text(); 
private double oldHeight = 0;


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    root.getChildren().addAll(yourSP());
    scene = new Scene(root,300,316);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

private ScrollPane yourSP(){

    content.setMinSize(300, 300); 
    textF.setPrefSize(260, 40); 
    textF.setLayoutX(20);
    textF.setLayoutY(20); 
    textA.setPrefSize(260, 200);
    textA.setLayoutX(20);
    textA.setLayoutY(80); 

    textA.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("texta.css").toExternalForm());
    content.getChildren().addAll(textA,textF);

    /*************************@Uluk Biy Code**************************/
    textA.setWrapText(true);
    textHolder.textProperty().bind(textA.textProperty());
    textHolder.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
            if (oldHeight != newValue.getHeight()) {
                oldHeight = newValue.getHeight();
                textA.setPrefHeight(textHolder.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() + 20); 
                System.out.println(textHolder.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
            }
        }
    });
    /****************************************************************/

    scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
    scroller.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); 
    scroller.setPrefSize(300, 316); 


    return scroller;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args); 

  }

 }
```

Of course the code can be adapted to fxml format, I just have not had enough time to do it, and here is the style of the `TextArea`:

```
.text-area > .scroll-pane{

-fx-hbar-policy:never;
-fx-vbar-policy:never; 

}
```

good luck for the continuation !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that I like the solution. It's hacky as hell but actually works a lot better then the one with `textHolder` - is more stable. It's written in Kotlin with TornadoFX. For Java it should work the same, but probably with a lot more lines of code ;)

The principle is basically the same, but instead of dedicated `textHolder` object we are using the actual `Text` node inside the `TextArea`.

```kotlin
class ExpandableTextArea : TextArea() {
    init {
        addClass("expandable")
        isWrapText = true

        children.onChange { a ->
            val scrollPane = a.list.first() as ScrollPane
            val contentView = scrollPane.content as Region
            contentView.childrenUnmodifiable.onChange { b ->
                b.next()
                if (b.list.size == 2) {
                    val group = b.list[1] as Group
                    group.children.onChange { c ->
                        val text = c.list.first() as Text
                        text.layoutBoundsProperty().onChange {
                            if (it != null) {
                                val targetHeight = it.height + font.size
                                prefHeight = targetHeight
                                minHeight = targetHeight
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you still need the same CSS to turn the scrollbars off:

```css
.text-area > .scroll-pane{
  -fx-hbar-policy:never;
  -fx-vbar-policy:never; 
}
```

Please note that here I'm also setting the `minHeight` because I want this node to expand "brutally" so it never has to scroll. You can remove that and leave setting the `prefHeight` but if there is not enough space the node will stop growing and will be scrollable by mouse but without the scrollbars which can be confusing.

BE WARNED: if for some forsaken reason the TextArea children tree structure changes this **will** blow up.